# Add Row To Bound DGV By Textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

I have demonstrate the DGV as per following way.
I am trying to add input of textbox into DGV as below.

## Unbound DGV:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewColumn srno =  new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, srno);
        DataGridViewColumn part = new  DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, part);
        DataGridViewColumn cts = new  DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        cts.ValueType = typeof(decimal);
        dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, cts);
        DataGridViewColumn rt =new  DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        rt.ValueType = typeof(decimal);
        dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, rt);
        DataGridViewColumn debit =new  DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        debit.ValueType = typeof(decimal);
        dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, debit);


    }
    // textBox EventHandler
     private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((Keys)e.KeyChar == Keys.Enter) 
        {
                int i = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                dataGridView1[1, i].Value = textBox1.Text;
                dataGridView1.Focus();

        }

    }
```

## Bound DGV:

```
       private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connstr = "server=.;initial catalog=maa;uid=mah;pwd=mah";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstr);
        con.Open();
        DataSet mydatasett;
        string dgv = " select srno,particulars,carats,rate,debit from depurchaseA";
        SqlCommand dgvcmd = new SqlCommand(dgv, con);
        SqlDataAdapter dgvdap = new SqlDataAdapter(dgvcmd);
        mydatasett = new DataSet();
        dgvdap.Fill(mydatasett);
        bindingsource2 = new BindingSource();
        bindingsource2.DataSource = mydatasett;
        bindingsource2.DataMember = mydatasett.Tables[0].TableName;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingsource2;

    }

   **//And textbox Event handler :**
   private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((Keys)e.KeyChar == Keys.Enter) 
        {
                int i = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                dataGridView1[1, i].Value = textBox1.Text;
                dataGridView1.Focus();

        }

    }
```

The above works fine on UnBound DGV but the same not works in Bound DGV. I wants to add the input of textBox into Bound DGV. Is there any simple way?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a simple solution for **Editing/Adding/Removing** Row of Datagridview To Evoke or

Suspend the source for temparory on specific event handler like below.

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((Keys)e.KeyChar == Keys.Enter) 
        {

                bindingsource2.ResumeBinding (); // OR bindingsource2.SuspendBinding();       
                int i = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                dataGridView1[1, i].Value = textBox1.Text;
                dataGridView1.Focus();

        }

    }
```

Here In my Case There is only ResumeBinding() Method is Works. The SuspendBinding() Method will utilize in different way.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //  private String connectionString = null;
    // private SqlConnection sqlConnection = null;

    btnBack.Enabled = true;
    sqlConnection.Open();

    dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;

    //cmd = new SqlCommand("update empinfo set empname=@empname, empAdd=@empAdd, empMobile=@empMobile where empid=@empid", con);
    cmd = new SqlCommand("empinfo_Insert_Update_Delete", sqlConnection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Insert_Update_Delete_EmpSal", sqlConnection);
    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    try
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empid", txtempId.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empName", txtempName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empAdd", txtempAdd.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empMobile", TxtempMobile.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intflag", 1);
        //txtempId.Text = txtsalempId.Text;
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salId", txtsalId.Text);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salAmount", txtsalary.Text);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salDate", txtdos.Text);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empId", txtempId.Text);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intflag", 1);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dataTable.Rows[i][3] = dataTable.Rows[0][3];
        }

        sqlDataAdapter.Update(dataTable);
        //int b;
        //b = int.Parse(txtempId.Text);

        //selectQueryString1 = "SELECT * FROM empsal where empid=" + b;
        ////sqlDataAdapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter(selectQueryString1, sqlConnection);
        ////sqlCommandBuilder1 = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqlDataAdapter1);
        ////dataTable1 = new DataTable();
        ////sqlDataAdapter1.Fill(dataTable1);
        ////bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
        ////bindingSource1.DataSource = dataTable1;
        ////dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;

        MessageBox.Show("data Updated");
    }
    catch (Exception exceptionObj)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exceptionObj.Message.ToString());
    }                    
    cmd1 = null;            
    dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
    sqlConnection.Close();
    clearText();

    addcolumn();
    childform();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but have you tried dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = textBox1.Text?

I would put a breakpoint in your texbox handler and check the value of dataGridView1.CurrentCell, make sure it's a single value and that it's pointing to what you expect it to, also.

Comment: It's Not working, it's the same way which i used above.it's doesn't make a diference.